# AsciiDoc add bold text inside a listing block

Tags: asciidoc, asciidoctor

Have some AsciiDoc that has a block like...

```
----
  this is a test
    with *some* formatted/tabbed text in it
blah
----
```

...and I would like the text to display like...

```
  this is a test
    with some formatted/tabbed text in it
blah
```

...where the word "some" is bold.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is what I came up with. This post was helpful...

http://www.methods.co.nz/asciidoc/faq.html#_how_can_i_format_text_inside_a_listing_block

```
[subs="quotes"]
----
  this is a test
    with *some* formatted/tabbed text in it
blah
----
```

This allowed me to retain the formatting/whitespace in the text in addition to adding the formatting (bold in this case) to the text.

Answer (score 5):

In AsciiDoc, the double `----` lines signify **ListingBlocks**, which only preserve certain formatting aspects of your text *(**line** and **whitespace** formatting)*, according to the [AsciiDoc documentation on Delimited Blocks](http://asciidoc.org/chunked/ch16.html) ( [with the exception of using](http://asciidoc.org/faq.html#_how_can_i_format_text_inside_a_listing_block) `[subs="quotes"]`, as you [noted in your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34656748/1167750)).

Other ways to include bold formatting in a delimited block include the **"Admonition Block"**, **ExampleBlock**, **OpenBlock**, **QuoteBlock**, and **SidebarBlock** [options](http://asciidoc.org/chunked/ch16.html).

---

**Example Blocks:**

```
**Admonition Block:**
[NOTE]
====
here *is* my text
====

**Example Block:**
====
here *is* my text
====

**Open Block:**
--
here *is* my text
--

**Quote Block:**
[quote, quote author]
____
here *is* my text
____

**Sidebar Block:**
****
here *is* my text
****
```

**Example Blocks Output:**

[image: Example Blocks Output]

Comment: Thanks summea. I updated the question to better reflect my problem. See my solution below. Please let me know if you have a better way to do this.

Comment: @Lumbee Nice find with the `[subs="quotes"]` attribute!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, this is only possible with docbook code, you can see an [example here](http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1230000000065/ch04.html#code_explanation):

```
++++
<screen>hostname $ <userinput>date</userinput>
Sun Apr  1 12:34:56 GMT 1984</screen>
++++
```

Of course, it will only work if your engine was configured with the correcting style for `screen` and `userinput`.