# asciidoc: Including bold inside Code Fence

Tags: asciidoc, asciidoctor

Ho can I include inside an asciidoc code fence? Here is a sample:

```
[source,js]
----
function doit() {
    *var thing;*        //  local variable
}
----
```

The idea is that I would like to highlight certain parts of the code block for teaching purposes.

The above sample doesn’t work.

I have read about using something like `[subs="macro"]`, but (a) I can’t get it working in combination with a code fence, and (b) the documentation is a little unclear about the actual details.

Thanks

BTW I am aware of a similar question [AsciiDoc add bold text inside a listing block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34641637/asciidoc-add-bold-text-inside-a-listing-block), but there is *no reference* to code fences. I have tried the solutions, but the don’t work in this context.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [AsciiDocs Documentation](http://asciidoctor.org/docs/user-manual/#applying-substitutions), below code

```
[source,java,subs="verbatim,quotes"] 
----
System.out.println("Hello *bold* text"). 
----
```

will be displayed as

> System.out.println("Hello **bold** text").

So, you need this -

```
[source,js,subs="verbatim,quotes"]
----
function doit() {

    *_var thing;_* //  local variable
}
----
```

It will be displayed as

[image]

`verbatim` and `quotes` subs are helpful.

NOTE:
One thing we need to keep in mind that the code block is already highlighting syntax. If you want different formatting, better not to use code block.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. (Sorry for the late response — I missed this earlier). You’re right in that the syntax highlighting may compete with additional formatting, but I can work around that.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion the philosophy of Asciidoctor for those use case is to use [callouts](http://asciidoctor.org/docs/user-manual/#callouts).

```
[source,js]
----
function doit() {
    var thing; // <1>
}
----
<1> local variable
```

The second thing you should consider is to extract your code from a real, controled, unit-tested file. You define some markers in this code file and add an `include` directive in your adoc file.

Check slides 15-21 in this presentation: 
[Writing documentation with Asciidoctor](http://www.slideshare.net/jmini/writing-documentation-with-asciidoctor)

Comment: I will be using callouts as well, but I particularly want to use bold to highlight changes from a previous example.